# How do I scale a container for the image contents inside?

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside of a container that scales correctly depending on the size on the screen. The issue is that the container will not scale with it height wise.

I want the image to fill the container completely and keep in the same aspect ratio of the image.

This is what I have got so far:

```css
.center-img {
    image-orientation: from-image;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 98%;
    height: auto;
}

.all-box-slideshow {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    width: 98.3%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-box-slideshow">
    <div>
      <img class="center-img" src="images/image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the `center-image` class on the image makes the image scale to the screen size through a percentage.

How can I scale the height of the container, as it does not leave room for the image inside?

Comment: Hi Elden, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you clarify how you want the image to appear? Do you want it to take up 100% of the container width or height? Or do you want it to fill both?

Comment: I would want the image to fill the container completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned your css and changed your img into a div with red border so we can see it.
I made the container with green color to see it too.

The point here was to give your img a `relative position` so the div around it will adapt.

```css
.img {
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
  width:93vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.all-box-slideshow {
    padding: 5px 5px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-box-slideshow">
    <div class="img">      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) To help you about why your css was not clean : `height:auto` is useless when you already fixed your element top and bottom. Same for the width. The proprety i used "vh" and "vw" means "viewport height" and "viewport width" and means that it will scale depending of the screen and NOT depending of the parent. Have fun with CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

This will force the image to fill the parent container completely, and will scale accordingly.

```css
.center-img {
 image-orientation: from-image;
 position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
    
 width: 98%;
 height: 98%;
}

.all-box-slideshow {
 padding: 5px 5px;
 width: 98.3%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-box-slideshow">
    <div>
      <img class="center-img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great but, would it be possible to keep the image in the same aspect ratio of the source image?

Comment: @EldenTheaker Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question. Are you saying you want the parent container to fit the image size?